# Can I make an Android button template?

Tags: android

I have several buttons in my current app.  They are all identical except for their text and a tag.  The main.xml would be a lot nicer if I didn't have to repeat all the button config information for each button.

Is there a way to define a button as template, and then make more using it as a template?

In this example, I have about 10 of the following:

```
 <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Y"
            android:typeface="monospace"
            android:textSize="12pt"
            android:tag="Y"
            android:textColor="@color/button_text"
            android:background="@drawable/grey_blank_48x48"
            android:onClick="onButtonClicked"/>
```

It would be nice if I had one, and then 9 of these:

```
 <Button2
            android:text="N"
            android:tag="N"/>
```

**Resolution**

It was pretty much as @Luksprog said:

```
<style name="ASR33_button" >
    <item name="android:id">@+id/button</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/button_text</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/grey_blank_48x48</item>
    <item name="android:onClick">onButtonClicked</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12pt</item>
</style>
```

with the main.xml having things like this:

```
   <Button
            style="@style/ASR33_button"
            android:tag="Y"
            android:text="Y"
            />

   <Button
            style="@style/ASR33_button"
            android:tag="N"
            android:text="N"
            />
```

This carries the day.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Us a [`style`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="btnlook" >
        <item name="android:id">@+id/button</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/button_text</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/grey_blank_48x48</item>
        <item name="android:onClick">onButtonClicked</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">12pt</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

and then in your xml layout:

```
<Button
            style="@style/btnlook"
            android:text="N"
            android:tag="N"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make a custom view that extends button and sets all the things that is repeating. Then you can use it as you described, but with a fully qualified name, not just shortname.

```
class MyButton extends Button {
    public MyButton() {
        // Set the values you want
    }
}
```

And in XML:

```
<com.me.myapp.MyButton
    android:text="N"
    android:tag="N" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `selector`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#AAFFFFFF"/>
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
        android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:topRightRadius="7dp"/>
```

And set the 10 button `android:background="@drawable/that_selecter"`

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this to make custom button subclassing the button.